# C# .net core: Multiple ajax forms with hidden inputs with same ID

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dom

I have a web page with multiple separate tabs, all exist in DOM, switching between them is entirely client-side. Each tab contains an ajax form for editing data of a selected app user. For eg. first tab lets you edit name, surname, ..., second tab lets you edit address. Each tab has a save button and each time only properties of current tab are propagated to the DB. All works well :)

BUT, of course, each tab needs PK of the user (user.Id) in question. Its passed to controller via a hidden field 
`<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />`, so *HTML DOM contains more than one element with the same id and browsers complain*.

I know that I could manually set the name/id of these input fields, and manually map them on the controller side, but model binder could do this for me, its nice and clean.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditGeneralData([Bind(GeneralDataBindFieldNames)]AppUser appUser)
```

Is there a nice & simple way to achieve this? Should I simply forget about the browser warning as I will be careful when/if using `getElementById`? Whats your take on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... not really the answer I was looking for, but it should suffice. It turns up that the content of these tabs is related to one another. So all the tabs cannot exist in the DOM at the same time, and switching between them cannot be entirely client side.

Now, tab click loads tab content on demand, so theres no multiple input fields in the DOM anymore. Only one tab at a time means only one input field at a time :)